# Access denied when table is recreated in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I created a new user and gave read-only access to the user for all the schemas with:

`alter default privileges grant select on tables to the user;`

Initially, the user had access but when the table was recreated the access automatically declined.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

How you are giving permission? Group level or User level.

Try below GRANT USAGE

**For Group level**

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA 'SCHEMA_NAMES' TO GROUP Group_name;
```

**For User level**

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA 'SCHEMA_NAMES' TO USER User_name;
```

Comment: I having a problem with both user and group level. Yes, I gave the usage permission to the user/group.attached the complete commands I used.                                                    
                                                                                                                             
          `grant usage on schema apps to group group_name;`

           `grant SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN schema apps to group group _name;`


          `alter default privileges in schema apps grant select on tables to group 
          group_name;`